# Creating and using an object after being inserted into DB [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have a user class and a database class:

User.js

```
const Database = require('./database')
const myDB = new Database()

function User (userID) {
  this.userID = userID
  myDB.insertUser(userID)
}
```

Database.js

```
function Database () {
  const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbName)
  db.serialize(() => {
    db.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${userTable} (user_id TEXT, balance INT)`)
  })
  db.close()
}

Database.prototype.insertUser = function (userID, cb) {
// code
}

Database.prototype.getName = function (userID, cb) {
// code
}
```

I want to do the following, but am unsure as to how to do it synchronously:

```
const john = new User('john')
console.log(john.getName())
```

What are the best practices on creating objects that are added to the DB but then used straightaway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insertion and reading from DB is an async operation, you have to use either callback or promise. I can see you have defined callbacks but not using it properly.

I'm assuming your insertUser and getName function looks like below.

```
Database.prototype.insertUser = function (userID, cb) {
  // code reading data
  cb(null,data)
}

Database.prototype.getName = function (userID, cb) {
  // code
  cb(null,data)
}


function User (userID,cb) {
  this.userID = userID
  myDB.insertUser(userID,cb)
} 

new User('john', (err, data) => {
    this.getName('john', (err, result) => {
        console.log(result);
    })
});
```